Friends iPhones Unable To See My MacBook Pro's Location on FindMyMac?
I do not have an iPhone, but I do have a Mac Book Pro. I recently shared my Mac Book's location with all my friends I had saved in my Mac's message's app (I have their iPhone numbers). I also asked them to share their locations with me. I can successfully see their locations (their iPhones), but they cannot see my location (my MacBook) on the FindMy app.
I'm not sure how to solve this problem, because my Location Services are turned on and I can see their locations. I can see my own Mac's location on Find My (it fully shows up), so its just all my friends that cannot see my location (on my Mac's messages app it says I have "shared my location" with them).
P.S: This is not too different from someone tracking their Mac and owning an iPhone simultaneously, so its not like this is some new situation. My cousins have their iMacs and MacBooks on Find My, etc.

Could you provide which macOS version you are running? I'm not 100% sure about about sharing location between Mac and iPhones, but I've noticed that sharing locations via iMessages between two iPhones, now requires that both iPhones be on the same iOS version. I think this is a recent change to how location sharing works between iPhones, because they previously could share locations even on different iOS versions.  Furthermore, I don't know if this changed requirement also applies to Find My app users, and definitely not sure how it would interact between iOS and macOS...

Small edit: It looks like Find My works between different iOS versions (just tested it), but when I requested my friend's location through iMessages, it wouldn't send the "request location notification" to them because they are on an older iOS version. I can still see them in Find My though... That said, this was all iOS to iOS. I'm not sure about iOS to macOS, so I suggest you update your question with your macOS version :)

My MacOS is Version 12.4 Monterey
